# We have an $n$ natural number. Prove, that $2(3n)!$ is divisible with $n!(n+1)!(n+2)!.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We have an $n$ natural number. Prove, that $2(3n)!$ is divisible with $n!(n+1)!(n+2)!.$

I tried to make it look simplier, but can't prove that this is true.

Comment: Is there a generalization to this problem for $n$ and $k$ is :$$  \frac{k!(n(k+1))!}{n!(n+1)!\cdots(n+k)!}$$ an integer?

Comment: @Elaqqad: Note that it is not an integer at least for $(k,n)=(3,1)$.

Comment: @mathlove, it's true if we replace the $k!$ by $(k+1)!$ it's true but it's not the minimal factor

Comment: @Elaqqad: For $k=3$, you can replace $k!$ by $12$ which is the minimal factor for $k=3$. See [this OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005790).

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Use the Legendre's formula.

Comment: Don't you mean Legendre's formula?

Comment: Oh yeah, the other one is for quadratic residues right? Thank you.